# Fazer inserções múltiplas no SQL, múltiplos inserts

Tags: php, mysql, sintaxe

Boa noite a todos, mais uma vez vivo meu calcanhar de aquiles com o bendito sql...

Estou querendo inserir dados em duas tabelas... tabela cliente e endereco.

Eu pego o sql abaixo, preencho as variaveis e executo o sql no phpmyadmin e funciona... ai pego o sql que deu certo e coloco no meu PHP e nada... não dá erro e nem insere...

Pesquisei algo relacionado a **mysql_insert_id()**, mas não sei se fiz certo.

Poderiam me ajudar nessa sintaxe?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `endereco` (`id`, `rua`, `numero`, `bairro`, `cidade`, `cep`) 
    VALUES (NULL, $logradouro, $numero, $bairro, $cidade, $cep);
       $xy = mysql_insert_id();
    INSERT INTO `cliente` (`id`, `nome`, `profissao`, `endereco`, `email`) 
    VALUES (NULL, $nome , $profissao, $xy,$email)";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está na execução de inserções múltiplas e o modo errôneo como montou as queries, misturando variáveis fora de escopo.

Por padrão, o SGDB (MySQL), não permite múltiplas queries numa única execução, exceto para casos do uso de transactions (BEGIN... COMMIT).

Para o seu caso específico, execute as queries individualmente para resolver o problema.

**Exemplo:**

```
// executa a primeira query
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `endereco` (`id`, `rua`, `numero`, `bairro`, `cidade`, `cep`) VALUES (NULL, $logradouro, $numero, $bairro, $cidade, $cep);");

// obtém o último id, o mais recente
$xy = mysql_insert_id();

// executa a segunda query
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `cliente` (`id`, `nome`, `profissao`, `endereco`, `email`) 
    VALUES (NULL, $nome , $profissao, $xy,$email);");
```

**Observações relevantes**

1. Evite o uso de funções mysql_* pois estão obsoletas. Procure usar PDO, MySQLi ou alguma biblioteca popular.
2. Há problemas lógicos na estruturas dos esquemas das tabelas.
   Procure estudar sobre modelagem de dados.
3. Múltiplas queries é diferente de múltiplas inserções, pois é possível aplicar múltiplas inserções caso a estrutura de dados das queries sejam idênticas, porém não vem ao caso explicar esse recurso para a questão presente.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa chamar a query do mysql dentro do php para funcionar, do jeito que você fez a variavel $sql esta entendendo o seu codigo como una string.

Vamos lá.

```
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO endereco(id, rua, numero, bairro, cidade, cep)VALUES(0,'$rua', $numero, '$bairro', '$cidade', '$cep'");
```

Repare que a variável $numero nao esta sendo inserida dentro de aspas pois estou supondo que na tabela o campo numero eh um int

Uma coisa legal para você ver erros em sql é adicionar um or die no final da query veja:

```
   $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO endereco(id, rua, numero, bairro, cidade, cep)VALUES(0,'$rua', $numero, '$bairro', '$cidade', '$cep'") or die(mysql_error());
    // se houver algum problema de sintaxe, o sql vai indicar para você
```

boa sorte